# Need to force Mac Address on OpenVPN virtual network device

Tags: openvpn, remote-connection

I need to use a software that connects to a server, that server validates the client-PC checking with the MacAddress of the network card.

On local, no issues... on remote no issues but, I want to use the software with OpenVPN to add a layer of priacy and security.

Issue is, OpenVPN virtual network card creates a new Mac wich is not validated by the software server. Is there any way to force OpenVPN connect to use the same Mac as the hardware network card ?

Thanks in advance.